# How to output the checkbox value in the email template EmailJS and React

Tags: reactjs

I am using EmailJS to send the form data to a mailbox and everything is working fine.
Except that I can't get the checkboxes output.
The user can select one or more checkboxes, but I can't get the output in the EmailJS email template.

```
const [toSend, setToSend] = useState({
        piva: '',
        codicefiscale: '',
        ragionesociale: '',
        sedelegale: '',
        sedeproduttiva: '',
        email: '',
        motivazione: '',
        tipoazienda: '', // checkboxes
    })

<fieldset required name="tipoazienda" value={toSend.tipoazienda} onChange={formrdoHandleChange} >
                    <legend>Tipo di azienda</legend>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="toolmaker" /> 
                    <label htmlFor="toolmaker">Tool Maker</label>

                    <br />

                    <input type="checkbox" value="tooluser" /> 
                    <label htmlFor="tooluser">Tool User</label>

                    <br />

                    <input type="checkbox" value="enduser" /> 
                    <label htmlFor="enduser">End User</label>
                </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out today!

so in your input, you would need to add an id like so

`<input type="checkbox" id="toolmakerID" value="toolmaker" />`

and inside your emailjs template, you will reference this by using curly brackets like so `{{toolmakerID}}`

hope this helps!